# The getter 'backColor' was called on null

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to extend the background color from one container in a class to another in a seperate class. I but after I run I get the following error. I have tried everything I know I am doing right but now I am confused. I don't even know what I am doing wrong any help
this is the error I get

The getter 'backColor' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: backColor

this is the first class;

```
class FoodDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FoodDetailsState createState() => _FoodDetailsState();
}

class _FoodDetailsState extends State<FoodDetails> {
  static get rate => double;
  static get color => Color; //This is what I am trying to get.
  final List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> demoFoods = [
    {
      'name': 'Burger n Fries +1',
      'price': '20.00',
      rate: 3.5,
      'clients': '250',
      'image': 'assets/images/coke.png',
      color: Colors.amber,
    },
    {
      'name': 'Peperoni Pizza',
      'price': '45.00',
      rate: 3.5,
      'clients': '400',
      'image': 'assets/images/pizza2.png',
      color: Colors.orange,
    },
    {
      'name': 'Regular Choco-Sundae',
      'price': '25.00',
      rate: 4.8,
      'clients': '300',
      'image': 'assets/images/regularsundae.png',
      color: Colors.purpleAccent,
    },
    {
      'name': 'Chicken Nuggets',
      'price': '40.00',
      rate: 5.0,
      'clients': '200',
      'image': 'assets/images/nugget1.png',
      color: Colors.orangeAccent,
    },
    {
      'name': 'Egg-Tart Pie',
      'price': '35.05',
      rate: 3.6,
      'clients': '10',
      'image': 'assets/images/eggtartpie.png',
      color: Colors.yellowAccent,
    }
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child: PageView.builder(
          itemCount: this.demoFoods.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            Map<dynamic, dynamic> product = this.demoFoods[index];
            return GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(
                  context,
                  'details',
                  arguments: {
                    'product': product,
                    'index': index,
                  },
                );
              },
              child: Hero(
                tag: 'detail_food$index',
                child: PopularCard(
                  width: SizeConfig.screenWidth / 2 - 30,
                  primaryColor: kPrimaryColor,
                  productName: product['name'],
                  productPrice: product['price'],
                  productUrl: product['image'],
                  productClients: product['clients'],
                  productRate: product[rate],
                  backColor: product[color], //I call in my code
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Then the second class with the first container;

```
class Details extends StatelessWidget {
  final PopularCard color; //I created a constructor for the color

  const Details({Key key, this.color}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final Map screenArguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
    Map product = screenArguments['product'];

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: product[color.backColor], //I called it
      appBar: constAppBar(),
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: size.height,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: getProportionateScreenHeight(500),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.3),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        topLeft: Radius.circular(24),
                        topRight: Radius.circular(24),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          product['name'],
                          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4.copyWith(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            RichText(
                              text: TextSpan(
                                children: [
                                  TextSpan(text: "Price\n"),
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: '\$ ${product['price']}',
                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                        .textTheme
                                        .headline4
                                        .copyWith(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
                            Expanded(
                              child: Image.asset(product['image']),
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the code of my popular card code as requested;

```
class PopularCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color primaryColor, backColor;
  final double width, productRate;
  final String productUrl, productName, productClients, productPrice;

  const PopularCard({
    Key key,
    this.primaryColor,
    this.width,
    this.productUrl,
    this.productName,
    this.productRate,
    this.productClients,
    this.productPrice,
    this.backColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: width,
      height: getProportionateScreenHeight(260),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.grey[300],
                        blurRadius: 4.0,
                        offset: Offset(3.0, 3.0),
                      ),
                    ],
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    color: backColor,
                    // Color(0xFFFAFAFA),
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage(productUrl),
                      fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: infoCard(),
                ),
                LikedWidget(primaryColor: primaryColor)
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Column infoCard() {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
      children: [
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 60,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20),
              vertical: getProportionateScreenHeight(5)),
          decoration: cardInfoDecoration,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    productName,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 18.5,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Spacer(),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                    decoration: likedWidgetDecoration,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.near_me,
                      size: 12.0,
                      color: primaryColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        '$productRate ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      buildSmoothStarRating(),
                      SizedBox(width: getProportionateScreenWidth(10)),
                      Text(
                        '\($productClients\)',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Spacer(),
                      Text(
                        '\$ $productPrice',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 15.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  SmoothStarRating buildSmoothStarRating() {
    return SmoothStarRating(
      allowHalfRating: false,
      onRated: (v) {},
      starCount: 5,
      rating: productRate,
      isReadOnly: true,
      size: 13,
      color: kRatingStarColor,
      borderColor: kRatingStarColor,
    );
  }
}

class LikedWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const LikedWidget({
    Key key,
    @required this.primaryColor,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Color primaryColor;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Positioned(
      top: 5,
      right: 20,
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
          decoration: likedWidgetDecoration,
          child: Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
            size: 15.0,
            color: primaryColor,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the routes class as requested;

```
    class NavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NavBarState createState() => _NavBarState();
}

class _NavBarState extends State<NavBar> {
  int selectedPage = 0;

  final List<Widget> _list = <Widget>[
    HomePage(),
    ExplorePage(),
    NearMe(),
    AccountPage(),
  ];

  void navTappedChange(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedPage = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: _list[selectedPage],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        elevation: 0,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.redAccent,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
        currentIndex: selectedPage,
        onTap: navTappedChange,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              CupertinoIcons.house_alt,
            ),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              CupertinoIcons.compass,
            ),
            label: 'Explore',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              CupertinoIcons.location,
            ),
            label: 'Near Me',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(
              CupertinoIcons.person,
            ),
            label: 'Account',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: This is the homepage with the popularcard(popular foods) below]

[image: When I click on the popular foods it should take me here with the background color {but as u can see no color}]

Comment: Can you share the code of your PopularCard?

Comment: Can you also share the `routes` property of your `MaterialApp`?

Answer (score 0):

You created but did not initialize it. You need to get an instance of PopularCard.

```
class Details extends StatelessWidget {
    final PopularCard color = PopularCard();
```

Comment: I did exactly that but now I dont see the color on the next page... I have updated the question as requested